# How can I tell, in onDraw, whether or not I'm inside Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a custom view that renders part of itself (*pink area*) in `onDraw`. It does this, via a class instance set via adapter/binding. I have no problem with the *117* and *details* controls at design time. However, this *pink area* **is** resulting in a call to `onDraw` within Android Studio.

[image]

Everything's ok at runtime. However, I am getting (and rightfully so) an Android Studio error message - because the class that I use to do the drawing hasn't been instantiated.

[image]

**So, my question is**:

> Can I detect, *in code*, whether or not the app is running (rendering really) inside AS (as opposed to having been deployed to an emulator or device)?**

It might be something like `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)`, or perhaps something [entirely] different. (There's certainly nothing [else] in the `BuildDebug` instance that'll help.)

Ultimately, I see my current

```
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        :
        :
        puzzle.doSomething
```

replaced with something like:

```
        if (!INSIDE_ANDROID_STUDIO)
            puzzle.doSomething
```

I spent over an hour searching online. With no luck. It's hard to ask "How do I know if I'm running in the Android Studio IDE?" and not get a bazillion links concerning:

- Why isn't Android Studio running [correctly]
- How to tell if another app is running
- How to tell if your app is in the fore or background
- Why this or that isn't rendering correctly

But nothing on point. I did numerous searches of "UninitializedPropertyAccessException" and "Render problem" as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by checking what returns the `isInEditMode()` method. If `true` your view is displayed in AS or other tool, otherwise - it`s on a device.

> Indicates whether this View is currently in edit mode. A View is usually in edit mode when displayed within a developer tool. For instance, if this View is being drawn by a visual user interface builder, this method should return true.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#isInEditMode()

Comment: Thanks! That absolutely did it. I did, however, discover something puzzling while implementing my changes: It was still "splatting" on a `Log.d` line. Which I `if (!isInEditMode)` [kotlin] and no more splat. The puzzling thing is: if it's splatting on the `Log` line, why is nothing actually being logged? Why is it executing these "nothing" lines? Or are they being logged somewhere/somehow? Logcat's "emulator dropdown" won't allow me to choose "none" and I've played with everything else there... Anybody have any thoughts on this?